# Can't Get JS Moment to Work in SharePoint with REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, momentjs, sharepoint-2013

I'm working in SharePoint 2013 using REST API to retrieve Date field values. I need to get the from now value of those fields and so I am using JS Moment, but so far I can't the moment code to work at all.  Here's some snippets of my SharePoint REST API code:

```
url:/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Contacts')/items?"$Select=Created,OData__x0031_st_x0020_Draft_x0020_Test",

$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) { 

var createdDate1 = $.format.date(value.Created, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
var createdDate2 = createdDate1.toString();
var createdDate3 = new Date(createdDate2);

var firstDueDate1 = $.format.date(value.OData__x0031_st_x0020_Draft_x0020_Test, 'd MMM yyyy');
var firstDueDate2 = firstDueDate1.toString();
var firstDueDate3 = new Date(firstDueDate2);
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
var createdDate4 = moment(createdDate3).toNow();
var firstDueDate4 = moment(firstDueDate3).toNow();

test1 = moment([2019, 1, 29]).fromNow(); //example from tutorials - Not relevant to what I'm doing
test2 = moment().subtract(5, 'h'); //example from tutorials - Not relevant to what I'm doing
```

Finally, here's my include for Moment:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dateFormat/1.0/jquery.dateFormat.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Has anyone else seen this problem?  If so please provide guidance and code examples.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where is the problem occurring? What errors do you see?

Comment: In any line using the "moment" phrase I get a "moment is undefined" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a from now value for ItemCreated Date which compare with Today, just use moment(item.Created).fromNow() will be working, please refer the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items",  
        type: "GET",  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() 
        },  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data)   
        {    
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)   
            {  
                var item = data.d.results[i];
                var createdDate = moment(item.Created);
                console.log(createdDate.fromNow());
            }  
        },  
        error: function(data)  
        {  
            console.log(data.responseJSON.error);  
        }  
    });  
</script>
```

[image]

[image]